# Google short url API error

Tags: short-url

We are using the Google API to shorten our URL. This API works for smaller URL but when we tried to shorten bigger URL then it throws **400** error. Is there any maximum limit to shorten the URL or there is any solution to resolve this error? Because sometime our becomes to big say suppose thousands of character at time it throws error.

Comment: Can anyone have solution for it.

Comment: How about posting an example?